# Kernel Mode Heap Corruption

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, windows-10-upgrade

I recently installed Windows 10 Creator Update in my Alienware. The worst part is the right after the update completed and I was granted access to log into my account, I get a BSOD. The stop code is: `KERNEL MODE HEAP CORRUPTION`.

How to fix this?

Note: I can't even get into my Windows. I only sit at the log in screen. Typing in my log in pin, brings back the BSOD every single time.

After some browsing I got this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/64ytqa/windows_creator_update_causes_bsod/) post where the user seem to have a similar problem as mine but he fixed it. Reading through the post, I figured out that I also have `UXStyle` installed so perhaps that might be causing the issue?

Now how do I either uninstall UXStyle from the outside or roll back to previous update without losing any of my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same thing happen. Alienware 17 R4 with UXStyle installed.  What I did to fix it was:

1. Let the computer try and boot into Windows three times, until you get to the recovery options screens
2. Select Troubleshoot
3. On the next screen, select Advanced Options
4. On the next screen, select Startup Settings
5. On the next screen, select Restart.

This will restart your computer and will bring you to the advanced startup options screen.  On that screen you will need to select option 4 (safe mode)

Once you successfully boot into safe mode, you will need to:

1. Uninstall UxStyle. If you can't (I couldn't), you will have to remove the following files:

   - `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\uxstyle.sys` (if present)
   - `C:\Windows\unsignedthemes.exe`
2. Issue the following commands from an elevated Command Prompt or PowerShell:

   - `sc delete uxstyle`
   - `sc delete UnsignedThemes`
3. Reboot to see if it solved your issue.

It worked for me.

Comment: This helped me, however i did  not find a uxstyle.sys thanks anyway!